# Can I bind to a property of an instance of an object

Tags: wpf

Ok, I've looked around on here and on google and can't find an answer to this, or I'm just not understanding something correctly.

I have a class called PLCValues. In this class I have a property called TrkPresent.

In my viewModel, I create an instance of PLCValues called values. I want to bind to the TrkPresent property of the values instance. Is there anyway to do this? Still new to WPF and MVVM for that matter. Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Your question is rather ambiguous, but assuming you have your `viewModel` as the [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext) of your control, then it would simply be `TargetProperty="{Binding values.TrkPresent}"` where TargetProperty is whatever property you are wanting to bind to.  What type is `TrkPresent`?  Is your `viewModel` instance set as DataContext?

Comment: That is the whole point of DependencyProperties and the binding system - to tell a property like `TextBox.Text` that it should go get it's value from another location, which could be the property of an instance of an object. If you are encountering an error trying to do that, I'd suggest editing your question to include some relevant bits of code, and what error you are getting, and we'd be happy to try and help you fix it.

Comment: Hey sorry for not replying sooner. TrkPresent is a bool Property. My view model is set as the data context. I can bind to Properties that are in the viewModel properly. They work perfect. Just can't bind to the properties of the instance I create.

Comment: You can't bind to it?  Or it doesn't update as you were expecting when you change the value?

Comment: It doesn't update as expected when I change the value.

Comment: Okay, so I figured it out guys. When I created the instance of the object, I had to make it a property as well. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured this out. When I created the instance of my object, in this case the values class. I had to create it as a property. So I said

`public Values values {get; private set;}`

then just declare it as normal in constructor of the viewModel:

`values = new Values();`

then when binding in xaml ensure that the DataContext is set to the viewModel containing the instance and bind to:

`{Binding values.TrkPresent}`

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to bind to that property assuming the values instance is public:

TargetProperty = {Binding Path=values.TrkPresent}